# Wordpress posts array contains only a reference to the home page

Tags: wordpress

Hi there just started working with Wordpress and trying to get a hang of how wordpress uses loops. I am using following tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVqzKAUsM68&list=PLmFwGfciLDFjWspYdKJ4hGaFqzR2ujeJZ

I have got to about 1 hour 23 mins into the tutorial where I have created basically an empty theme: index.php, style.css and screenshot.png.

I have just created 3 posts which are public and published.

I now want to list the three posts with their title and content and to do so I write the following code in the index:

```
<?php 
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        //echo wp_count_posts();
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
    <h3><?php echo the_content();?></h3>
    <hr>
    <?php

    }
}
?>
```

I expect to see the title of the 3 posts I have plus the relevant content.

What I see is the title of the home page and the home page content.

What I understood was that I was in the posts loop and therefore should see post data.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220590/loop-code-is-displaying-pages-but-not-actual-posts

Code to get posts (from the reference, written by user [frogg3862](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/83367/frogg3862)):

```
/* You can replace your original loop with the code below. This will query 10 posts
and return their titles.
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for customizing it. */

$args = array(
 'post_type'         => 'post',
 'posts_per_page'    => 10
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   echo '<ul>';
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       $the_query->the_post();
       echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WordPress World!
It is because you changed front page setting in settings/reading tab.
Please change back to Your latest posts then you will see what you want.

[image]

For your information you need to study [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) before start editing template files.
Hope this help you.
By the way you need to use the_title(); and the_content(); instead of echo the_title() and echo the_content(); (it's default action is echo)

Comment: Thanks so much it instant result  : -)